# Unable to click sign in/out button using python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a code where I can auto sign in and sign out on HR Portal i.e. "https://newage.greythr.com/". However, I'm unable to click the sign in/out button after logging in. Initial part of the code is working fine but the bottom part i.e. **# Sign in/out** is giving **InvalidArgumentException** error. I've tried 2 alternatives both mentioned below in the code but none of it is executing and giving the same error. Also, I tried to increase the wait time still it failed.
If anything is required from my end kindly let me know in comments section.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/Selenium Drivers/chromedriver.exe')

# Open the website
driver.get("https://newage.greythr.com/")

time.sleep(2)

# Defining username & password
username = "****"
password = "****"

time.sleep(2)

# Entering username
user = driver.find_element("id", "username")
user.click()
user.send_keys(username)

time.sleep(2)

# Entering password
psw = driver.find_element("id", "password")
psw.click()
psw.send_keys(password)

time.sleep(2)

# Click login button
driver.find_element("id", "password").submit()

# Sign in/out

time.sleep(10)

driver.find_element("XPATH", "//button[contains(.,'Sign In')]").click()
```

```
**Upper part is same as above**

# Sign in/out

sign = driver.find_element("XPATH", "/html/body/app/ng-component/div/div/div[2]/div/ghr-home/div[2]/div/gt-home-dashboard/div/div[2]/gt-component-loader/gt-attendance-info/div/div/div[3]/gt-button[1]")

time.sleep(20)

sign.click()
```

Comment: Don't use `time.sleep()`, Selenium has this function that waits until the element is present on the page, this is an example from a code that I wrote `WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "/html/body/iframe")))`, In your case should be something like this `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id="username"]")))`

Comment: See more about here https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be using 'xpath' argument or import the By module and do it like

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(.,'Sign In')]").click()
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution but I tried using pyautogui with some Tabs and it is working perfectly. Thanks for the answer your are awesome.